# Is it possible to exclude comments from searches using silversearcher

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, terminal, grep

I am searching through files that contain large comment blocks. These comment blocks contain `javadoc` style code comments that also contain the keywords I am searching for.

For a query like,

`$ ag compute`

I would like to exclude any matches that are found within such comment blocks that contain the keyword `compute`. Is this possible with [silversearcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher). Any alternative approach to this problem is also welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: There's an extant feature-request on this topic on `ag`; you might wish to add your `+1` there: https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/issues/543

Answer (score 1):

You might try something like this. It will filter all lines with a `*` in it.

```
ag 'TODO' . | grep -v '*'
```

This solution is not perfect, but `--ignore` does only work for files. If anybody has a better solution I am also interested in it.